Can the class of ordinals be extended even further?
Is it possible for anything to come after all ordinals? I don't see why not. For example, one can take a non-ordinal set $S$, and then add in all the ordered pairs $(\alpha, S)$ to $ON$, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal, thereby making a well-ordered proper class of "order type" $ON + 1$. But now, here is my real question, is this a valid and legitimate thing to do? And also, has anyone studied or written about these proper class well-orderings which are longer than $ON$?

This is a good question, but has been asked before - see e.g. What order types can well-ordered proper classes have?
